# Can I refer to the template's base class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Is there a way to refer to the base class of the currently provided template? For example,

```
template <class UserType>
class User
{
    public:
        User()
        {
            user_manager_ = std::make_unique<UserType>();
        }

   private:
        std::unique_ptr<UserType::Base> user_manager_; // <-- I want this ptr to be the type of base of UserType i.e. IUserManager
}
```

Comment: C++ has no reflection. You could impose your own requirement that every class used with this template must define an inner `Base` type. Exactly like all containers in the C++ library define `value_type`, `iterator`, etc...

Comment: Unless the `UserType` really have a `Base` type defined, then it's not possible. It's even less possible to get a single base class considering that C++ allows multiple inheritance. If `UserType` inherits from multiple bases, which one would you pick?

Comment: Also, what is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you need a pointer to the base class? Going from the names of your variables and types, why would a "user" class inherit from a "manager" class? A "user isn't a "manager" (remember that inheritance is an "is-a" relationship). Perhaps a better choice would be for `UserType` to have a function that returns a pointer to the "manager" object?

Comment: There may be multiple base classes, so keep that edge case in mind. Also, whilst not directly answering your question, if you have a set of base classes that you want to check against you can use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Makes sense what you said. Regarding the names, they are just hypothetical names I came up with. The actual problem is different. I guess I wanted to imply "creating a manager according to user type" but doesn't really matter as it is just hypothetical I wrote. The actual point is I want the pointer to be of type interface of the template class. Your explanation makes sense why it is not possible. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? XY problem?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, because of multiple inheritances in c++. The only way to do something similar is:

```
struct A {};

struct UserType : public A {
  using Base = A;
};

template<class UserType>
class User {
 public:
  User() {
    user_manager_ = std::make_unique<UserType>();
  }

 private:
  std::unique_ptr<typename UserType::Base> user_manager_; // <-- I want this ptr to be the type of base of UserType i.e. IUserManager
};
```